# Cant get soapUI groovy script to monitor a testsuite and wait until its finished

Tags: asynchronous, groovy, soapui

I have a scenario where i have 4 test suites in SOAPUI and each one of them have  test cases which can be executed in parallel. But only one suite can be executed at once.

There is monitoring functionality which can only monitor test case but not the suite for its completion.

So can someone please help me with executing such a scenario.

Thanks

```
def testSuites = context.testCase.project.getTestSuiteList()
def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap()
log.info("Number Test Suites Present in the Project :- "+testSuites.size())
testSuites.each 
{
        log.info("########################################################")
            def testCases = it.getTestCaseList()
            log.info("Number Test Cases Present :- "+testCases.size())
            testCases.each  
            {
                    log.info("Running the Test Case :- "+it.name)
                    runner = it.run(properties, true)
            }
            // Here after all test cases are kicked off asynchornously, I would like to wait until the suite is finished
}
```

Comment: Put all the suites under one project. Run the project.Setting for testcases should be in parallel and settings for testsuite should be sequential.

Comment: Thanks Gaura.

But all my suites are already part of one project. Can you help me in understanding how to set the project.setting.

Comment: please check the answer added and let me know if helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these options highlighted in image

1 option :- Select that at project level. It will make the the suite runs one after the other

2 option :- Select that at suite level. It will make the test cases run in parallely

[image]

[check point 2 here](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html)